# Can I split /boot to a different partition on a single partition system?

Tags: boot, partitioning

The title says it all.
I have set up my system, configured it and everything, using only one partition for / (ext4). So no separate home, boot, swap etc.

So the question is: Is there a way to go from this configuration to a 'separate' partition thing?

Can I make room for a separate boot partition and maybe copy my /boot there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gparted` from the livecd to resize the partition to make some room and create a new partition to move /boot to, but why would you want to?

If you really want to ( and I don't recommend it ), once you create the new partition, you will need to mount it somewhere and copy everything in /boot to it ( for example, with `cp -ax` ), unmount it, edit /etc/fstab to mount it in /boot, then mount it there and reinstall grub.  You can do the last part by running `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc`.

Comment: Thans @psusi very much. I was obviously missing the reinstall grub part! I want to do that because later I will also convert the / partition to encrypted, and that needs a separate boot partition from what I'm reading. Well, that will be the point of my next question, how to convert / to encrypted using dm-crypt etc.

Comment: @nick ahh yes, that is a good reason for a separate /boot.